# QT/C++ Commit a value to other class

Tags: c++, qt

I have some problems in QT to commit a QModelIndex from class myDialog to the mainWindow Class.

In myDialog.cpp I have following function:

```
void myDialog::accept(){
QModelIndex index = ui->folderElectionView->currentIndex();
connect(SIGNAL(folderElection::accept()), this, Slovari::folderElected(index));
//Slovari s;
//s.on_folderElected(index);
}
```

and in mainWindow as public slot:

```
void folderElected(QModelIndex index){
...do something with the index
}
```

I tried it also with the code in comment, but I think generally signal and slot is the correct way!?

Comment: Generally you connect the signal where you know the Slot, not where the signal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is faulty in many ways. It looks like that it doesn't even compile.
I could fix it, but I think it is bad idea since logic of your code looks faulty too, so fixing this will doesn't help you either.

IMO you should describe what kind of functionality are you trying to achieve.
I'm *suspecting* that this should look like more or less like that:

```
myDialog::myDialog(QWidget *parent) : 
        QDialog(parent) {
    ...

    connect(this, SIGNAL(accept(QModelIndex)),
            somthingEles, SLOT(folderElected(QModelIndex));
}

void myDialog::accept(){
    QModelIndex index = ui->folderElectionView->currentIndex();
    emit accept(index);
}

void folderElected(QModelIndex index){
    ...
    // do something with the index
}
```